# How to figure out the parameters from mppm in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I am working using the **spatstat** library in **R**.

I have several point pattern objects built from my own `dataset`. The point patterns contain only the x and y coordinates of the points in them. I wanted to fit the point patterns to a **Gibbs process** with **Strauss interaction** to build a model and simulate similar point patterns. I was able to use **ppm** function for that purpose if I work with one point pattern at a time. I used **rmhmodel** function on the ppm object returned from the `ppm` function. The `rmhmodel` function gave me the parameters `beta`, `gamma` and `r`, which I needed to use in **rStrauss** function further to simulate new point patterns. FYI, I am not using the **simulate** function directly as I want the new simulated point pattern to have flexible number of points that simulate does not give me.

Now, if I want to work with all the point patterns I have, I can build a `hyperframe` of point patterns as described in the **replicated point pattern** chapter of the `Baddeley` textbook, but it requires **mppm** function instead of ppm function to fit the model and `mppm` is not working with `rmhmodel` when I am trying to figure out the model parameters `beta`, `gamma` and `r`.

**How can I extract the fitted `beta`, `gamma` and `r` from a `mppm` object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

If you `print` a fitted model (obtained from `ppm` or from `mppm`) simply by typing the name of the object, the printed output contains a description of the fitted model including the model parameters.

If you apply the function `parameters` to a fitted model obtained from `ppm` you will obtain a list of the parameter values with appropriate names.

```
fit <- ppm(cells ~ 1, Strauss(0.12))
fit
parameters(fit)
```

For a model obtained from `mppm`, there could be different parameter values applying to each row of the hyperframe of data, so you would have to do `lapply(subfits(model), parameters)` and the result is a list with one entry for each row of the hyperframe, containing the parameters relevant to each row.

```
A <- hyperframe(Bugs=waterstriders)
mfit <- mppm(Bugs ~ 1, data=A, Strauss(5))
lapply(subfits(mfit), parameters)
```

Alternatively you can extract the canonical parameters by `coef` and transform them to the natural parameters.

You wrote:

> I am not using the `simulate` function directly as I want the new simulated point pattern to have flexible number of points that `simulate` does not give me.

This cannot be right. The function `simulate.mppm` generates simulated realisations with a variable number of points. Try `simulate(mfit)`.

Comment: Thank you. About the `simulate` function: suppose I am fitting a model with a point pattern with 100 points. When I am trying to use the `simulate` function to create new point patterns, the new one has points around 100. How can I make it create point patterns with suppose 1000 points keeping the fitted model characteristics the same? I am flexible with the size of the window also, as in if needed the window can be larger to accommodate 1000 points now.